# Installing grub2 in yocto rootfs

Tags: yocto, grub2

I am working on yocto, I want to include grub2 exectables such as grub2-mkconfig in my filesystem.

I am able to install grub in yocto, by adding below line.

```
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS = "grub"
PREFERRED_VERSION_grub ?= "1.99"
```

when I change

```
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS = "grub2" or 
MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS = "grub_2"
```

I got below error

```
ERROR: Nothing RPROVIDES 'grub2' (but /home/poky/meta/recipes-core/packagegroups/packagegroup-core-boot.bb RDEPENDS on or otherwise requires it)
NOTE: Runtime target 'grub2' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['grub2']
NOTE: Runtime target 'packagegroup-core-boot' is unbuildable, removing...
Missing or unbuildable dependency chain was: ['packagegroup-core-boot', 'grub2']
```

How can I include grub2 support?

Comment: The recipe of 'grub 2' is also just 'grub'. Does it work to set MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS to 'grub' and PREFERRED_VERSION_grub ?= "2.00" or "2.%"

Comment: I canged MACHINE_ESSENTIAL_EXTRA_RDEPENDS to 'grub' and PREFERRED_VERSION_grub ?= "2.00" still i have "grub-mkconfg" rather than grub2-mkconfig

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This question is not off-topic. Yocto is the major cross-platform build system used today for embedded Linux software development.